# RMI with multiple hosts

Tags: java, rmi

I'm working on a program that uses RMI for 2 connections, one from client to server, and onether for communication between 2 virtual machines on the client.

It seems the RMI registry has to run on the server (otherwise I get `java.rmi.AccessException: Registry.Registry.rebind disallowed; origin <client ip> is non-local host`). In addition, the client could not connect to the server without first calling `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", <server ip>);`.

So I tried creating a registry on both the server and the client. The communication from one virtual machine on the client to the other is done using a second registry created on the client. This second registry is created without complaints. However, because I had set the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property before, I get another exception: `java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: <server ip>`.

I have a dirty solution in place; in stead of every `Registry.rebind()` for the client registry, I call

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "localhost");
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.
Remote stub = (Remote) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(remote, 0);
registry.rebind(name, stub);
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", <server ip>);
```

Is there a better way to deal with this problem? Can two registries be created and used cleanly, or can client and server share a registry?

Comment: Why are you using 0 as port in exportObject? Use two different ports when creating registry as well as exporting object and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to writer `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", <server ip>);` in the client because hostname defines the application's hostname for locally binded registry objects. See here: [java.rmi Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/javarmiproperties.html)

You don't even need to run registries on different ports. Just try to keep it simple. If anything is unclear you can ask again.